# Create a subset of the full data to only keep those observations with the ID’s that you got from the matching procedure

Tags: r, subset, matching

Here is my code

```
wave1 <- subset(danish, wave==c(1))
library(MatchIt)

match.out <- matchit(ever_treated ~ 
                 benefitW1 + benefitW2 + male + age + wrkst + highered + income, 
                 data = wave1,
                 distance = "mahalanobis",
                 replace = F, 
                 method = "genetic",
                 estimand = "ATT",
                 ratio = 1)
summary(match.out)


plot(summary(match.out), 
     abs = F,
     position = "topleft",
     var.order = "unmatched")

matched.id <- match.data(match.out)$id
```

Now I have to create a subset of the full data which is "danish" but only with the matched.id instead of all the previous id and I don't know how to do that, if anyone knows the answer that would really help.
Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your data with something like `dput()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.